# AWS + DynamoDB + API gateway takes time

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Our tech stack:
DynamoDB + Node.js + Aws Lambda + API Gateway.

As of now we don't have much data in database, around 100 records total. At time of fetching we have used `GSI` with `query` over `scan` for fast result and also used limit with 10.  But still it does not  return response fast. For just `10 records` it takes `898.50 ms`.

Can anyone help, how to reduce this response time as this is the initial stage of development.

Why it takes this much for this? How we can get faster response and what affects the performance.

Example Code:

```
const itemParams = {
    TableName: CUSTOMER_TABLE,
    IndexName: 'companyId-index', // GSI Without range key
    KeyConditionExpression: 'companyId = :companyId',
    ProjectionExpression: [
      'id',
      'companyId',
      'fullName',
      'companyName',
      'mobileNumber',
      'contactEmail',
      'createdAt',
      'updatedAt'
    ],
    FilterExpression: 'isDeleted = :isDeleted',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':isDeleted': false,
      ':companyId': authCompanyId
    }
  };

const customerList = await dynamoUtils.query(itemParams);
```

Note: function just execute query in dynamo, does not have any complex calculation neither in lambda function itself nor in dynamo query.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can add active tracing for the lambda and api gateway to debug latency bottlenecks in x-ray. Latency is often caused by small lambda sizes (smaller than 1GB memory) or a number of other things like huge package sizes being included in the lambda. X-ray gives insights in that without any code changes. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-xray.html

Comment: What is the configuration of your lambda function? Use a tool like https://github.com/alexcasalboni/aws-lambda-power-tuning to figure out the most cost effective memory configuration

Comment: @LRutten Thanks for reminding about memory. We checked that we are using 128MB memory. Also checked by increasing memory and performance increased. But have query that, in cloudwatch log, max memory used is less than 100MB then why should we have to increase memory?

Comment: Memory also increases CPU and decreases cold starts significantly. Usually after 1GB memory it doenst add much value any more unless you have huge package sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using very small lambda sizes (256MB or less) can get quite slow for cold starts that need to download some packages. This is because the memory of the lambda is strongly correlated to other performance metrics like CPU available to the lambda.

Increasing the memory to 1GB or optimizing it using a tool can significantly reduce this time.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Comment: have one another query. Why response time is different when call frequently and when we call after some times. For example if I call any API 3-4 times continuously then it takes less time compare to the first request. May be because of caching or something?

Comment: Could be lambda cold start or caching indeed